# Python hash table design

Tags: python, hash

I want to implement a hash table in python. On the table a class object will be associated with the key value. The problem is I want to use the key value to find the index of the class and update it (which of course is not a problem). But what can I do if I want to sort the table using a particular value of the class.

For example, let us consider, we have three value: document_id, score and rank. There is a class "document" which consists of "score" and "rank". "document_id" will be the key of the table.

I want to update the "score" of various entries of the table, using the key: "document_id". But when updating of the scores are done, I want to sort the list/table using the score and assign rank value to the "rank" variable based on updated score.

Can someone kindly give me some guideline about how can I proceed? Or maybe I should simply make it a list?

The maximum number of item of the table might be upto 25000-30000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python's dict is already a hash table.

```
doc_hash = {}
doc_hash[doc.id] = doc
```

To assign rank:

```
docs = sorted(doc_hash.itervalues(), key=operator.attrgetter('score'), reverse=True)
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    doc.rank = i
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I try to update the rank every time I update/insert a document, won't the order of the loop increases rapidly, rather than a sorting at the end of all insertion/updating? I wont be doing anything more with the ranks. After sorting them out, I will just put them in a file.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "increases rapidly"?  You can add a bunch of docs, and then reassign the ranks all at once at the end.  I misspoke about "every time you insert one."

Comment: I am sorry, if it is at the end of adding docs, then it is okay. I was talking about the size of the table. I thought if I try to run some sorting every time I enter/update an entry in a huge table then it might become a lengthy process.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I am soory there has been some edit so the comments are not making enough sense. At the problem I told about it. After updating the entries I wanted to sort them based on particular field. Thats what I was talking about.

Comment: You can't sort a hash. Hashes aren't sequences. If you want to keep the values in a sorted order, then use an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a `OrderedDict`?

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda element: element['score'])
for i in range(len(sorted_keys)):
  d[sorted_keys[i]]['rank'] = i
```

assigns to each element in `d` (elements are implied to be dictionaries as well) a rank based on its score.

Comment: Learn about `enumerate`.  It will make you happy :)